# Suppress indentation after environment in LaTeX

Tags: latex, indentation

I'm trying to create a new environment in my LaTeX document where indentation in the next paragraph following the environment is suppressed.

I have been told (TeXbook and LaTeX source) that by setting `\everypar` to `{\setbox0\lastbox}`, the TeX typesetter will execute this at the beginning of the next paragraph and thus remove the indentation:

```
\everypar{\setbox0\lastbox}
```

So this is what I do, but to no effect (following paragraph is still indented):

```
\newenvironment{example}
  {\begin{list}
     {}
     {\setlength\leftmargin{2em}}}
  {\end{list}\everypar{\setbox0\lastbox}}
```

I have studied LaTeX's internals as well as I could manage. It seems that the `\end` routine says `\endgroup` and `\par` at some point, which may be the reason LaTeX ignores my `\everypar` setting. `\global` doesn't help either. I know about `\noindent` but want to do this automatically.

Example document fragment:

```
This is paragraph text. This is paragraph text, too.

\begin{example}
  \item This is the first item in the list.
  \item This is the second item in the list.
\end{example}

This is more paragraph text. I don't want this indented, please.
```

Internal routines and switches of interest seem to be `\@endpetrue`, `\@endparenv` and others. Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, the LaTeX source actually provides hooks for the problem at hand. It comments: "To suppress the paragraph indentation in text immediately following a paragraph-making environment ... [redefines `\everypar` and `\par`]" This is done in `\@doendpe`, which will be expanded if `\@endpetrue` -- but to no effect.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112404/reliable-code-for-automatic-noindent-after-specific-environments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get anything to work without redefining `\end`, but I'm certainly no expert.

The following is quite hacky, but worked in my limited testing.  Of course this will interfere with nested environments (you should be able to redefine `\begin` to restore the old `\end` if you have problems).

```
\newenvironment{example}{%
  \bgroup
  \let\oldend=\end
  \def\end##1{\oldend{##1}\csname @afterindentfalse\endcsname
                          \csname @afterheading\endcsname}
  \begin{list}{}
    {\setlength\leftmargin{2em}}
  }{%
  \end{list}
  \egroup
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, sorry. I get a few LaTeX errors "can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode" and missing or extra braces and $ (the syntax of my document is fine, though).

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that it should be between \makeatletter
 and \makeatother.  I've updated the answer to reflect this by using \csname

Comment: Oops, I had forgotten about `\makeatletter` for a second, sorry about that. Yes, this solution is quite hackish, and I have to admit that it does bug me that I can't find a more elegant solution with `\@doendpe` and friends ... In any case, your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can't you avoid this by not having a blank line between your environment and the next line?

```
This is paragraph text. This is paragraph text, too.

\begin{example}
  \item This is the first item in the list.
  \item This is the second item in the list.
\end{example}
% (No blank line)
This is more paragraph text. I don't want this indented, please.
```

Comment: Of course, I can. But since the `\section` etc. commands can do what I'm looking for (no indentation in the following paragraph even if there are blank lines in between), I'm hopeful that it can be done in an elegant and general way, if somewhat low-level.

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as this works for me:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{example}{%
  \bgroup
    \list{}{}
}{%
    \endlist
    \@afterindentfalse
    \@afterheading
  \egroup
}
\makeatother
```

But, it doesn't work before the first \section (or \chapter, in the case of classes "book" and "report") is called. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2742156/1105514), but it wasn't working for me.  But I did get it working!  Here's what I did:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quotation}{% 
\bgroup%
\let\oldend=\end%
\def\end##1{\oldend{##1}\csname @afterindentfalse\endcsname%
                        \csname @afterheading\endcsname}%
\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
\itemindent    \listparindent%
\leftmargin 1.5em%               This controls the size of the indentation
\rightmargin   \leftmargin
\parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%      This line reduces inter-paragraph space to normal values.
\item\relax%
}{%
\endlist%%
\egroup%
}
\makeatother
```

The advantage to this is that it typesets your blockquotes very nicely, and removes the indentation from paragraph after the blockquote.

Answer (score 1):

## You can do this without redefining `\end`

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{example}
   {\begin{list}
      {}
      {\setlength\leftmargin{2em}}}
   {\end{list}%
    \def\if@endpe{%
      \@doendpe
      \let\par\@@par
      \iffalse}}
\makeatother
```

### Explanation

`\end` changes `\everypar` *after* expanding `\endexample`. To make things even more complicated it sets `\par` to restore `\everypar{}`. Appearently `\@doendpe` is ment to make sure that there is no indentation if the paragraph continues after the environment, but to restore normal behavior if there is a `\par` (or empty line) after the environment.

You may want to avoid changing `\end` because it would have to be changed at the begining of the environment and may therefore disturb nested environments. Luckily the definition of `\end` contains `\expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe`. We can use `\if@endpe` as a hook to inject our code to the outer scope. After the `\endgroup` `\if@endpe` is automatically restored.

Answer (score 0):

Include \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading at the end of your definition.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just used this:

```
\noindent \newenvironment
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not mess with the `\everypar` token list, unless you know exactly what you are doing. Use

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

to get rid of indenting in the whole document.

Comment: I'd like to get rid of indentation _only_ after some environment. Since plain tex can apparently do it (see TeXbook, p. 10), LaTeX should, too.

Answer (score -2):

ending your environment with \noindent could help you

Comment: You might want to not give simple answers to year old questions, the person has probably moved on.

Comment: Also, this seems more appropriate as a comment instead of answer.